# AWS API Gateway: What does the POST method does not work and ANY method works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am facing `Missing Authentication Token` error while calling a POST method and keeping all things alike and changing the method to ANY is working fine. Both these APIs are bound to a AWS-Lambda function. What is the difference between these two methods and why do you think is this happening? Do I need to enable anything else for POST method?

Comment: Your API endpoint is probably configured to accept only GET requests. You need to explicitly tell it to accept POST, if that's the method you want to use.

Comment: How do I check this? This is the sequence of steps I followed 1. Create API 2. Create Resource 3. Create Method (POST) this gave me "Missing authentication token" 4. Create Method (ANY) this works fine

Comment: Are you sure you're sending `POST` requests? Where are the requests being originated: from a backend script, from a Javascript frontend, or else? Beware that API Gateway returns the `Missing Authentication Token` for errors that are unrelated to an auth token. The error messages are badly designed, but anyway, if you request a non-existing endpoint, it will return the auth token error, for example, instead of a 404-like error message.

Comment: I invoke the end point using the browser and curl command. I am passing the parameters as https://endpoint?parm1=something&parm2=something and the api returns a json

Comment: Would you be able to post here the command you're using in cURL and in the browser to call the API endpoint?

Comment: I just click on the invoke url, something like this: https://9oexxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/stage-name/api-name?parm1=xxxx&parm2=xxxx. In curl I just do curl followed by this url. I have the parameters to be passed defined under the body mappig template within the integration request.

Comment: It seems you're sending the data as a GET request, not POST (URL parameters - the data after ? sign). Are you using cURL in Linux or in a language such as PHP? Could you post your actual code or cURL command? Otherwise I can't help you further...

Comment: I confirm that when I create a GET method it works just fine. I though it doesn't matter whether its a GET request or a POST request, but clearly thats not the case. Do you have any links that explain the difference between these methods and which method to use when?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=get+and+post+requests